# R chunk code stay inside the Beamer frame

Tags: r, knitr, beamer

Here is my MWE code.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

<<setup, include=FALSE>>=
# smaller font size for chunks
opts_chunk$set(size = 'footnotesize')
options(width=60)
@


\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Test1}

<<boring-random>>=
y <- c(5, 7, 15, 17, 17, 19)
Trt <- gl(n = 3, k = 2, length = 3 * 2, labels = paste("Trt",
1:3, sep = ""), ordered = FALSE)
Data <- data.frame(Trt, y)
Fit1 <- aov(formula = y ~ Trt, data = Data, contrasts = list(Trt = "contr.sum"))
ANOVA1 <- anova(Fit1)
Coeffs1 <- coefficients(Fit1)
@
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm struggling to keep the R chunk code within the Beamer frame. I wonder what is the efficient way to manage the R chunk codes such that they stay inside the Beamer frame. Thanks

Comment: Would using something like `tidy.source` from the formatR package be an option?

Comment: `knitr` uses `tidy.source` by default, and width is determined by `getOption('width')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best approach is to turn off the `tidy` option by `tidy=FALSE`, and manually break your lines.

```
<<boring-random, tidy=FALSE>>=
y <- c(5, 7, 15, 17, 17, 19)
Trt <- gl(n = 3, k = 2, length = 3 * 2, labels = paste("Trt",
  1:3, sep = ""), ordered = FALSE)
Data <- data.frame(Trt, y)
Fit1 <- aov(formula = y ~ Trt, data = Data,
  contrasts = list(Trt = "contr.sum"))
ANOVA1 <- anova(Fit1)
Coeffs1 <- coefficients(Fit1)
@
```

This will always work. The other way is to set smaller `width` in `options()` ([knitr FAQ 8](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/FAQ.md)), and you probably need to try a few times for an ideal `width`. In your case, 60 is apparently too big.

Comment: It can also help to decrease the text margins slightly, e.g. put `\setbeamersize{text margin left = 16pt, text margin right = 16pt}` in your preamble, as [in this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/204205/21118).